# Auto filter copy paste loop between two tables loops forever and returns blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops, autofilter

As a preface, I stuck these codes together and have only a very basic idea of how they work.

I made a Macro to autofilter a table (It data[Surname]) and return based on the selected cell in another table (HR Data [Surname])

```
    Selection.Copy '~~>This is the (HR table [Surname]) cell
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    Sheets("AD").Select '~~>This is (It data)
    Dim sFilter               As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .getfromclipboard
        sFilter = .gettext
        sFilter = VBA.Replace$(VBA.Replace$(sFilter, vbCr, ""), vbLf, "")
    End With
    
    If sFilter <> vbNullString Then ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=sFilter, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    Call sourceSheet.Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    Call Filter_AD_by_first_name
End Sub
```

Then I made another macro to autofilter a table (It data[firstname]) and return another copied value (IT data [email]) based on the selected cell in the same table I search previously HR Data(firstname)

```
    Selection.Copy
    
    Sheets("AD").Select
    Dim sFilter               As String

    On Error Resume Next
    With GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .getfromclipboard
        sFilter = .gettext
        sFilter = VBA.Replace$(VBA.Replace$(sFilter, vbCr, ""), vbLf, "")
    End With
    If sFilter <> vbNullString Then ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=sFilter, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Select
    Selection.Copy '~~>This copies the email of the filtered column
    Sheets("Usermatch").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
    Call Filter_sn_by_Copied_data
End Sub
```

You can see I set them to loop back to each other and use ActiveCell.offset to continue down the table.

I have three problems with my code which I need help with if anyone is willing.

1. If sFilter <> vbNullString* I thought this should check for whether the resulting value is empty but
   I am unsure how to get it to add the term "empty" instead of copying a blank value if it is empty. Do I need to add an *else*?
2. I would also like it to write plaintext "duplicate" at this stage
   "ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas" if the
   filter returns more than one value. this is because if there are two staff members with the sam ename the macro will just copy and pick the name which is higher in the table.
3. I would also like to stop the loop if the *selection.copy* stage returns a blank.

Sorry for the complexity of the issues. I think I have reached the limit of my current ability to work this out on my own. Any advice on any of these problems would be appreciated.

Best,
Iain

Comment: you need to remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur you just cannot see their messages. If you don't see the errors you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code does not work. Remove that line and fix your errors (or tell which errors you get and where).

Comment: 1) `sFilter <> vbNullString` checks if the string variable is an empty string it is the same as `sFilter <> ""` • 2) I don't get this question. • 3) Which loop? There is no loop. • Please [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and try to adapt this technique to your code. Also try to give an example of what is wrong in your code or an [mvce]. Screenshots might help too to explain. Your question is pretty hard to understand.